# How to send login details to webserver from ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am quite confused about sending the login details to webserver.I have partly completed the process howvever am not able to proceed forward , since I am not able to understand the complete process.

This is what i have done.

```
- (IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
NSString *userName = self.userNameTextField.text;
NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.16:8080/WebServices/Authentication.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:userName forKey:@"pseudo"];
[dictionary setObject:password forKey:@"pass"];


NSData *data = [dictionary copy];


[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(!connection){
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");


}

}
```

And when I try to run the app after putting the login details , my app crashes ...saying.

```
   2013-12-27 20:00:00.177 Authentication[6820:380f] -[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c265e0
  (lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the

```
[dictionary copy]
```

returns a `NSDictionary` object, not `NSData` one. That's why you are getting an exception. What you need to do is convert the dictionary to `NSString` (XML or JSON) and create `NSData` object from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)loginUser:(id)sender {
    NSString *userName = self.userNameTextField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.16:8080/WebServices/Authentication.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *postParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pseudo=%@&pass=%@", userName,  password];

    [request setHTTPBody:[postParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dictionary setObject:userName forKey:@"pseudo"];
[dictionary setObject:password forKey:@"pass"];

NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://192.168.1.16:8080/WebServices/Authentication.php"];

NSMutableURLRequest urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theUrl];
NSError *error;

       NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString;

if (!jsonData) {
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

[urlRequest setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody: jsonData];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];



NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
if(!connection){
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
}
```